# How to get an array of all enum values in C#?

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum that I'd like to display all possible values of. Is there a way to get an array or list of all the possible values of the enum instead of manually creating such a list? e.g. If I have an enum:

```
public enum Enumnum { TypeA, TypeB, TypeC, TypeD }
```

how would I be able to get a `List<Enumnum>` that contains `{ TypeA, TypeB, TypeC, TypeD }`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert enum to list in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167361/convert-enum-to-list-in-c)

Answer (score 206, accepted):

This gets you a plain array of the enum values using [`Enum.GetValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx):

```
var valuesAsArray = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enumnum));
```

And this gets you a generic list:

```
var valuesAsList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enumnum)).Cast<Enumnum>().ToList();
```

Comment: This makes me always wonder why `Enumnum.GetValues()` and `Enumnum.GetNames()` doesn't exist.

Comment: For an array variable where the element type is known at compile-time, use `var valuesAsArray = (Enumnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enumnum));`.

Comment: Or `Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enumnum)).Cast<ActualType>().ToList();`

Comment: @mr5: In your example, what should `ActualType` mean? For an enum, it would be `Enumnum` in the OP's example, or it could be the underlying type (usually `int`). Did you have anything else in mind?

Comment: If you want an ordinary array, use 
Enum.GetValues(typeof(TSomeEnum)).Cast<TSomeEnum>().ToArray();

Enum.GetValues returns System.Array

Or use direct cast:

(TSomeEnumType[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(TSomeEnumType))

This is the shorted syntax. If you want an array
the answer above shows this.

Comment: As written in another answer this now  has a generic overload. `Enum.GetValues<Enumnum>();`

Answer (score 20):

Try this code:

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(Enumnum));
```

This return a `string[]` with all the enum names of the chosen enum.

Comment: Returns *names* of the enum values; OP seems to be after the *values* themselves.

Answer (score 15):

This is way easier now with the generic method in .NET 5.0.

```
ColorEnum[] colors = Enum.GetValues<ColorEnum>();
```

[MS Doc: Enum.GetValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-5.0#System_Enum_GetValues__1)

Answer (score 8):

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enumnum));
```

returns an array of the values in the Enum.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to do like this:

```
public enum Enumnum { 
            TypeA = 11,
            TypeB = 22,
            TypeC = 33,
            TypeD = 44
        }
```

All int values of this `enum` is `11,22,33,44`.

You can get these values by this:

```
var enumsValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enumnum)).Cast<Enumnum>().ToList().Select(e => (int)e);
```

`string.Join(",", enumsValues)` is `11,22,33,44`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum)).Cast<SomeEnum>().ToArray();
```

This returns an array!

Answer (score 4):

Something little different:

```
typeof(SomeEnum).GetEnumValues();
```

Answer (score 2):

with this:

```
string[] myArray = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Enumnum));
```

and you can access values array like so:

```
Array myArray = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enumnum));
```

Comment: Enum.GetValues doesn't return a string[]

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer a more generic way, here it is. You can add up more converters as per your need.

```
    public static class EnumConverter
    {

        public static string[] ToNameArray<T>()
        {
            return Enum.GetNames(typeof(T)).ToArray();
        }

        public static Array ToValueArray<T>()
        {
            return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
        }

        public static List<T> ToListOfValues<T>()
        {
            return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().ToList();
        }


        public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>()
        {
            return (T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
        }

    }
```

Sample Implementations :

```
   string[] roles = EnumConverter.ToStringArray<ePermittedRoles>();
   List<ePermittedRoles> roles2 = EnumConverter.ToListOfValues<ePermittedRoles>();
   Array data = EnumConverter.ToValueArray<ePermittedRoles>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The OP asked for How to get an array of all `enum` values in C# ?

**What if you want to get an array of selected `enum` values in C# ?**

**Your Enum**

```
    enum WeekDays 
    {
        Sunday, 
        Monday,
        Tuesday
    }
```

If you want to just select `Sunday` from your `Enum`.

```
  WeekDays[] weekDaysArray1 = new WeekDays[] { WeekDays.Sunday };

  WeekDays[] weekDaysArray2 = Enum.GetValues(typeof(WeekDays)).Cast<WeekDays>().Where
  (x => x == WeekDays.Sunday).ToArray();
```

Credits goes to knowledgeable tl.

References:

[1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160267/how-to-create-an-array-of-enums)

[2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123548/convert-enum-to-list)

Hope helps someone.

Comment: This method works for me. Namely the use of linq to set the data post cast

Answer (score 0):

also you can use

```
var enumAsJson=typeof(SomeEnum).Name + ":[" + string.Join(",", Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum)).Cast<SomeEnum>().Select(e => e.ToString())) + "]";
```

for get all elements in enum as json format.