# Convert Enum to List

Tags: c#, list, enums, type-conversion

Say i have the following Enum Values

```
enum Language
    {
       CSharp= 0,
        Java = 1,
        VB = 2

    }
```

I would like to convert them to list of values (i.e) `{ CSharp,Java,VB}.`

How to convert them to a list of values?

Comment: Take a look at [Enum.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
Language[] result = (Language[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Language))
```

will get you your values, if you want a list of the enums.

If you want a list of the names, use this:

```
string[] names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Languages));
```

Answer (score 14):

If I understand your requirement correctly , you are looking for something like this

```
var enumList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Language)).OfType<Language>().ToList();
```

Comment: Why do `OfType<Language>().ToList()` when you can just cast it straight to a `Languages[]`?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Yep you are correct

Answer (score 9):

If you want to store your enum elements in the list as Language type:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(Language)).Cast<Language>().ToList();
```

In case you want to store them as string:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(Language)).Cast<Language>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   enum Days { Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri };

    Array arr = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Days));
    List<string> lstDays = new List<string>(arr.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        lstDays.Add(arr.GetValue(i).ToString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: That's way too complicated.