# Reflection : Convert the returned property value based on Property Data Type

Tags: c#, reflection

**First question is not duplicate.**

public class Sample
    {
      public VehicleEnum Keyword { get;set;}
    }

```
public enum VehicleEnum { CAR = 0 , BIKE = 1 };
```

---

```
object modelObject = Activator.CreateInstance("ModelAssembly", "ModelAssembly.Sample");
object propValue = modelObject.GetType().GetProperty("Keyword").GetValue(modelObject);
```

1. Is there any way to return value in string data type(i.e. "Car").
2. Is there anyway of getting the list of Enumeration values as list of strings (not only assigned value) i.e. In this case, {"CAR", "BIKE" }

**Answer to the first question. :-)**
**Instead of the object, use the ObjectHandle and unwrap object.**

```
    ObjectHandle modelObject = Activator.CreateInstance("ModelAssembly","ModelAssembly.Sample");
 if (modelObject != null)
            {
                PropertyInfo memInfo = modelObject.Unwrap().GetType().GetProperty("Keyword", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                if (memInfo != null)
                {
                    object value = memInfo.GetValue(modelObject.Unwrap());
                    if (value != null)
                        propertyValue = value.ToString();
                }
            }
```

2. Same applies to 2nd question as well and has been answered in this post.

Comment: 1. `propValue.ToString()` 2. `Enum.GetNames(typeof(VehicleEnum))`

Comment: Both questions were asked like 1000 times: 1st is a simple `ToString()`, 2nd is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17123548/1997232).

Comment: VehicleEnum as object is not known as I am accessing it via Reflection. Request to read the question carefully. See below answer which worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var property = modelObject.GetType().GetProperty("Keyword");
        var propValue = property.GetValue(modelObject);

        foreach (var s in Enum.GetNames(property.PropertyType))
            Console.WriteLine(s);

        Console.WriteLine(propValue.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Convert.ChangeType(object, Type)` to cast to any desired type, although if you are only interested in string types, you can always use `object.ToString()`

To access the string representations of an enum, use `Enum.GetNames(Type)`

Comment: There's no need to call `ChangeType` here at all.

Comment: Because ToString() would suffice in this case, or because it would have unwanted/erroneous results? I mostly brought it up because it's more general than ToString(), although I agree that ToString() is preferable if strings are all you are and ever will be interested in.

Comment: I edited my answer to communicate that ToString() is preferable in the simpler cases.