# Converting enum values into an string array

Tags: c#, linq, enums

```
public enum VehicleData
{
    Dodge = 15001,
    BMW = 15002,
    Toyota = 15003        
}
```

I want to get above values 15001, 15002, 15003 in string array as shown below:

```
string[] arr = { "15001", "15002", "15003" };
```

I tried below command but that gave me array of names instead of values.

```
string[] aaa = (string[]) Enum.GetNames(typeof(VehicleData));
```

I also tried `string[] aaa = (string[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(VehicleData));` but that didn't work too.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you prefer a more generic implementation, [You can find it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47545368/3436775) .

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use [GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(VehicleData))
    .Cast<int>()
    .Select(x => x.ToString())
    .ToArray();
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/qNaj66)

Answer (score 43):

What about Enum.GetNames?

```
string[] cars = System.Enum.GetNames( typeof( VehicleData ) );
```

Give it a try ;)

Comment: `Enum.GetNames` returns array of string not a single string

Comment: `System.Enum.GetNames` will give names and not values as OP as asked for.

Answer (score 9):

`Enum.GetValues` will give you an array with all the defined values of your `Enum`. To turn them into numeric strings you will need to cast to `int` and then `ToString()` them

Something like:

```
var vals = Enum.GetValues(typeof(VehicleData))
    .Cast<int>()
    .Select(x => x.ToString())
    .ToArray();
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5Iq8IL)

Comment: It seems as though your demo doesn't correspond to your shown example.

Answer (score 3):

I found this here - [How do I convert an enum to a list in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167361/how-do-i-convert-an-enum-to-a-list-in-c), modified to make array.

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(VehicleData))
.Cast<int>()
.Select(v => v.ToString())
.ToArray();
```