# enumerating over all bools

Tags: c#, boolean, ienumerable

Not exactly a big deal to do this one myself, but I am curious if C# gives this to me anywhere:

```
public static IEnumerable<bool> AllBools {
  get {
    yield return false;
    yield return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a case where this would be useful at all?

Comment: BooleanConverter.GetStandardValues().  A hammer that does not need a nail.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code, a bit clunkier than you probably want, but it works:

```
    public static IEnumerable<bool> BoolValues {
        get {
            return new bool[]{true, false};
        }
    }
```

Edit: if you want code to enumerate over all values of an enum (which would be a lot more useful, imo), here is also the code:

```
    public enum TrueOrFalse
    {
        True,
        False
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TrueOrFalse> BoolValues {
        get {
            List<TrueOrFalse> allValues = new List<TrueOrFalse>();
            foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TrueOrFalse))){
                allValues.Add((TrueOrFalse)(value));
            }

            return allValues.AsEnumerable();
        }
    }
```

Even simpler, as found here ([How to get an array of all enum values in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816718/return-an-array-of-all-enum-values-in-c-sharp)):

```
 List<TrueOrFalse> valuesAsList =  Enum.GetValues(typeof(TrueOrFalse)).Cast<TrueOrFalse>().ToList();
```